# At Command: AT+QASP, AT+EASP

Tags: gsm, at-command, hyperterminal

guys!
I have been working with some logs of GSM modules, where I had found these these 2 AT commands: AT+QASP, AT+EASP. I surf through the net, but google didn't give me any information about them.
I have an example of the input, it looks like these:

AT+QAPS=1,4,3,"0.479.0.0.4096.8192.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0"
AT+EAPS=1,4,3,"0.479.0.0.4096.8192.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0"

Does anybody have any idea about what these 2 commands are supposed to do?
Any help is appreciated, thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Commands are responsible for sound settings and they are equivalent commands, but it is recommended to use QAPS command
The syntax of QAPS command.
AT+QAPS=1,4,,”...............”
Params are pesponsible for:
0-2, 12: Acoustic echo control
3-6, 8-11 : Noise and dynamic range control
7:  digital gain
13-14: Dual microphone noise reduction
15: N\A

Source: technical support of quectel
More info here: https://yadi.sk/d/IhUSoYu5uDj5Y